# Why doesn't () => this return the enclosing object?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Just for context, not important: I'm using this code to replicate some behavior in a Node.js/Express controller action for use in testing with Mocha. I'm returning the value of `this` from the `status` method for the purpose of method chaining (`res.status(200).json()` is used in the controller action), so the `json` method can be called on `res`, since it's an Express method on the response object.

It seems from my Mocha test run that the value of `this` (the `res` object) is correctly returned in the first snippet, in which I use ES6 concise method syntax to return `this`, but not the second code snippet, where I try to use an arrow function to implicitly return `this`. I thought using an arrow function would have the same result, since in arrow functions, the value of `this` is the enclosing lexical scope (seemingly the `res` object in this case).

Works as expected; `res` is seemingly returned as value of `status` method call

```
const res = {
  status() {
    return this;
  },
  json: () => {},
};
```

Doesn't work as expected (`res` seemingly not returned as value of `this` for `status` method call):

```
const res = {
  status: () => this,
  json: () => {},
};
```

Why doesn't `() => this` return the enclosing object?

Comment: "*in arrow functions, the value of `this` is the enclosing lexical scope*" - not exactly, it's the value of the `this` value in the enclosing lexical scope. "*seemingly the `res` object in this case*" - no, the object literal (even if "enclosing the arrow expression") does not form a lexical scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao according to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

> In arrow functions, `this` retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's `this`. In global code, it will be set to the global object:

```
var globalObject = this;
var foo = (() => this);
console.log(foo() === globalObject); // true
```

So basically write `() => this` and `this` in arrow function is the same thing.